# Amplify API Reference

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am having a really difficult time navigating the API reference.  The old AWS SDK for java used to have all used classes labeled with their proper parameters, errors thrown, and return values.  I am not finding this with Amplify.

Currently I am trying to understand the Amplify.storage class for Android.  The closest reference I can find for it is here,
https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/storage.html

The problem is that it does not describe the function used by their tutorial, `Amplify.Storage.downloadFile()`

This all seems to be the javascript implementation of this and not the java based SDK so maybe that is the problem.  I've been digging around on google and I can't find anything useful, is there reference material out there that I am just not finding or is this what we have to work with?

As I dig I keep getting linked back to the tutorial which is very frustrating because I want more information than what the tutorial provides.

Answer (score 3):

The Amplify Android project does not currently publish its Javadoc.

I have created [an issue for this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/651) on the Amplify Android GitHub repo.

For the time-being, your best bet is to read the source code, which *does* contain JavaDoc. The API for the storage category is [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/blob/main/core/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/storage/StorageCategoryBehavior.java#L43).

Comment: I had a question earlier that I saw you looked over.  I deleted it though as I found there was actually no issue with Amplify.  I wanted to notify you of that but this is the best I can do.  The real error was caused by my own code in trying to work with Amplify and Coroutines.  My repository was getting a null response because the suspend function wasn't set up correctly.  I am going to try to use suspendCoroutine to get this to work. 
 Amplify was working just fine, thanks!